# How to fix this code in counting duplicates per row with multiple column?

Tags: powerquery

Need help to fix this code that I tried in order to count duplicates for multiple rows and column per current row.

This is the simplest I can think of

```
Table.AddColumn(Source, "Add",
each List.Count(
Table.SelectRows(
    Source,
    (C) => List.Intersect(Table.ToList(Source),C(Table.ToList(Source)))=5
)[Column1]
))
```

It has the following error -

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type Function.
Details:
    Value=Record
    Type=Type
```

Here is the sample representative data:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+--------------------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Count of Dup 5 | Comments           |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+--------------------+
|       1 |      12 |      17 |      25 |      27 |      39 |              2 | -row line 1 and 2  |
|       1 |      12 |      17 |      25 |      27 |      44 |              2 | -row line 1 and 2  |
|      98 |      99 |     100 |     101 |     102 |     103 |              1 | -only current line |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: 1) `C` is a record, yet you try to call it like a function `C(Table.ToList...)`. 2) [List.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-intersect) takes a list of the lists to compare as the first argument. 3) `List.Intersect` only returns items that are common among **all** lists that are being compared. 4) You cannot directly compare two records, you would have to turn them into lists first. See [Table.ToRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-torows) and [Record.ToList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/record-tolist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[List.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-intersect) isn't really a good fit for counting duplicate rows as this function will only return those items that are common among **all** of the compared lists and will only return those items once.

All of the three options below do basically the same, just with slightly different approaches.
We add a calculated column that takes the current record, filters the whole dataset for records with the same values ([Table.SelectRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-selectrows) / [List.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-select)), and counts the filtered result ([Table.RowCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-rowcount) / [List.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-count).
Since two records with the same values are not treated as equal, both records to compare first have to be turned into lists, either by calling [Record.ToList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/record-tolist) on each record, or [Table.ToRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-torows) on the whole dataset.

## Option 1

Turning each table row into a list during the comparison.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Dupes = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Dupes", (CurrentRecord) =>
        Table.RowCount(
            Table.SelectRows(Source, (CompRecord) =>
                Record.ToList(CurrentRecord) = Record.ToList(CompRecord)
            )
        )
    )
in
    Dupes
```

## Option 2

Turning the table into a list (table) of lists (records) before comparing.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Dupes = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Dupes", (CurrentRecord) =>
        List.Count(
            List.Select(Table.ToRows(Source), (CompRecordAsList) =>
                Record.ToList(CurrentRecord) = CompRecordAsList
            )
        )
    )
in
    Dupes
```

## Option 3

Turning the table into a list (table) of lists (records) before comparing and using a variable to avoid repeated calls to `Record.ToList`.
I don't know how expensive `Record.ToList` is. For large datasets this could improve performance.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Dupes = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Dupes", (CurrentRecord) =>
        let
            CurrentRecordAsList = Record.ToList(CurrentRecord),
            ReturnValue = List.Count(
                List.Select(Table.ToRows(Source), (CompRecordAsList) =>
                    CurrentRecordAsList = CompRecordAsList
                )
            )
        in
            ReturnValue
    )
in
    Dupes
```

## Edit based on clarification in comments

### Option 4

Looking for common values independent of columns.

Since you are only interested in counting rows where exactly `n-m` column values out of `n` columns are equal we can indeed use [List.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-intersect) instead of a direct equality comparison.
The below is based on *Option 3* but would work the same in all three cases. We replace `CurrentRecordAsList = CompRecordAsList` with a call to `List.Intersect` on those two lists (where each list represents a single record, i.e. each list item represents the value in one of the columns), count the number of common items, and compare with `n-m` (which is `5` in this case).

**Careful #1:** Items that where *all* columns match are no longer counted, which means that the resulting number now only represents the *other* records. The current record, which was counted in the equality comparison, is not included.
Equality comparison: `1` means no duplicates (only found self)
Intersec comparison: `1` means one *other* record has been found

**Careful #2:** This will not check that the common values are in the same columns across the compared records. Only that the values occur *somewhere* in both records.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Dupes = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Dupes", (CurrentRecord) =>
        let
            CurrentRecordAsList = Record.ToList(CurrentRecord),
            ReturnValue = List.Count(
                List.Select(Table.ToRows(Source), (CompRecordAsList) =>
                    List.Count(List.Intersect({CompRecordAsList, CurrentRecordAsList})) = 5
                )
            )
        in
            ReturnValue
    )
in
    Dupes
```

### Option 5

If you also need to check that the common values are in the same columns, `List.Intersect` is no longer helpful.

What's happening below follows the same approach as before. We add a calculated column that takes the current record, filters the complete dataset, and counts the filtered records. Only that the filter criteria is a little more complex now.
The custom function used to filter the dataset uses [Table.ColumnNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-columnnames) to get the list of column names, filters this list ([List.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-select)) by using [Record.Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/record-field) to compare the corresponding column of both records, counts the resulting common columns ([List.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-count)) and compares that to the threshold `n-m` (e.g. `5`).

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Dupes = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Dupes", (CurrentRecord) =>
        Table.RowCount(
            Table.SelectRows(Source, (CompRecord) =>
                List.Count(
                    List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), (ColumnName) =>
                        Record.Field(CurrentRecord, ColumnName) = Record.Field(CompRecord, ColumnName)
                    )
                ) = 5
            )
        )
    )
in
    Dupes
```

Comment: Really appreciate your time to provide solutions.  It does work but what Im trying to do is check not all full rows

Comment: Then please clarify in your question what you are looking for, including sample data and expected results.

Comment: -Sorry this was sent out before i was able to finish the comment-

Really appreciate your time to provide solutions.  It does work but what Im trying to do is count the rows that only have 5 duplicate out of currently 6 columns in a row hence I tried to limit with below:

    List.Count(List.Intersect(Table.ToList(Source),C(Table.ToList(Source))))=5

any suggestion?

Comment: here are the sample data:
     Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Count of Dup 5 

    1 12 17 25 27 39 2 -row line 1 and 2

    1 12 17 25 27 44 2 -row line 1 and 2

    98 99 100 101 102 103 1 -only current line'

Comment: @theo Updated the answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  Thank you very much. It takes a long time though to process and I used option 3.  I have 5million rows so far and it increase everyday.

Comment: @theo With a dataset of that size you should really consider ditching Excel and using a database instead.

Comment: I read on microsoft access - and I think it will work.  Would you know the corresponding query formula in access with the one you have provided?  I can create a new post if required

Comment: [Something like this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/739JNLZc63DfDJvharMqQX/0) should work. This is MySQL, though. Not sure how well that translates to Access being that Access is a bit weird with its SQL dialect. And keep in mind that comparing every row with every row is never going to be fast with large datasets (with 5 million rows you are looking at 25 trillion combinations). So you may also want to rethink what question you are asking from your data and if this is the best way to find your answer..